# Create a favorite selection in Gridview using Sharepeference

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i am beginner in flutter now i want  Create a favorite selection in Gridview  using Sharepeference for storing favourite item from gridview  and mark it as as favouite[image: something link this image pleae check it].so when user close app and come back app they can see favouite inside gridview  you can check my code below  my code is not very complex its simple code you can easily understand this code!

```
import 'package:favorite_button/favorite_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/Singleimage.dart';

class CategoriesDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  late String categoryname;
  late int categorynumber;
  late String foldername;


  CategoriesDetails(this.categoryname, this.categorynumber,this.foldername);

  @override
  _CategoriesDetailsState createState() => _CategoriesDetailsState();
}

class _CategoriesDetailsState extends State<CategoriesDetails> {
   late List<String>addfavourite=[];
   late SharedPreferences prefs ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(widget.categoryname),
  ),
  body:Container(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: GridView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.categorynumber,
      gridDelegate:SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {


        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
             Expanded(
             child: Stack(
               alignment: Alignment.topRight,
               children: [
               Container(
                     margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:10, horizontal:6),
                     height: 200,
                     width: 200,
                     color: Colors.amber,
                     child:  GestureDetector(
                       onTap: (){

                         Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Singleimage(widget.foldername,widget.categorynumber,index,widget.categoryname)));

                       },
                       child: Image.asset(
                         'assets/images/${widget.foldername}/${index+1}.jpg',
                         height: 100,
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                       ),
                     )
                 ),
                 Positioned(
                   top: 0,
                   right: 0,
                   child: IconButton(
                     onPressed: () async {

                       },
                     color: Colors.white,
                     icon:Icon(Icons.favorite_border)

                   ),
                 )
               ],

             ),
           ),
                Text(
                '${index+1}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white
                ),)

              ],

            ),
          ),
        ) ;

      },

    ),
  ),

);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't save list obj directly in sharedprefrence
1)first covert into *MAP*  2)decode it into string variable
3) then encode it via json
4 covert it into list object and save in share pref

Comment: but in flutter shareperfernce. store list item directly using this method         prefs.setStringList(key, value)